# How to execute test cases in robot framework with input from a file

Tags: robotframework

Iam using robot framework to execute my test cases. My objective is to execute only the test cases that are present in the input file..any idea on how to do that will be appreciated.

Comment: To rephrase, you want to execute specific cases out of the whole set, that are given as - what - lines in a file? What is each line - a test case name, a location, a tag? You have to be much more specific, to get meaningful answers.

Comment: Each line in the file shall have the tag of the test case to be executed. I am aware of the fact that we can use command line argument --include to include only the specified test cases. But what I want is to provide an input file instead of command line argument more suitable for my automation use case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue and had to check robot source code but unfortunately I could not find and mention to running file based on a config file or related. I'd suggest, as you mentioned, using the --include, --exclude or -test options in command line.

Also, the RobotFramework documentation in this link talks about it [Documentation about running tests with tags or test names](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#by-tag-names)

Answer (score 0):

Tags are created for this purpose. So use tags and for example yaml-file to select, which test to run. See:
https://robocorp.com/docs/setup/robot-yaml-format